# How do I pass Django's urlize template filter its autoescape parameter?

Tags: django, django-templates

Django [`urlize` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) say:

> The `urlize` filter also takes an optional parameter `autoescape`. If `autoescape` is `True`, the link text and URLs will be escaped using Django's built-in `escape` filter. The default value for autoescape is `True`.

I'd like to use this parameter, but the documentation says nothing about how to actually pass a keyword argument to a template filter. Is it possible, and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `urlize` gets that keyword argument from current autoescape settings, so the way to go seems like

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ value|force_escape|urlize }}{% endautoescape %}
```

(if you still want to escape the value)